# Как скрыть отображение введенной команды в дискорд боте?

Tags: discord

Есть бот в дискорде, командой /boost add добавляю данные для бота, который в последствии подключается куда нужно.
Есть такой вопрос, как можно скрыть отображаемые данные введенные этой командой? Потому что на команду может нажать любой пользователь и увидит все введенные данные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Удалить сообщение?...

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос решен, используем эфемерные сообщения, тогда они видны только пользователю.

ephemeral (bool) – Indicates whether the deferred message will eventually be ephemeral. This only applies to InteractionType.application_command interactions, or if thinking is True.
ephemeral (bool) – Indicates if the message should only be visible to the user who started the interaction. If a view is sent with an ephemeral message and it has no timeout set then the timeout is set to 15 minutes.